# Graphing an elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: graphing-functions, elliptic-integrals

Is there any way to graph an elliptic integral of the first kind on Excel or some other graphing software that is free?

Comment: WolframAlpha can plot EllipticF (e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+EllipticF%5Bx%2C0.99%5D%2Fx) but that may not be flexible enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In *Mathematica*:

```
Plot[EllipticF[\[Phi], 0.5], {\[Phi], 0, Pi/2}]
```

which can also be done in [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BEllipticF%5B%5C%5BPhi%5D%2C%200.5%5D%2C%20%7B%5C%5BPhi%5D%2C%200%2C%20Pi%2F2%7D%5D) (for free).

[image]

Comment: Yep....  of course.  Thanks.